# Conversion of the candles array from the response to List of Historical Object. Additional details in the body

Tags: c#, arrays, json, facebook-c#-sdk

I have following object getting return from one of the API.

```
{{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "candles": [
      [
        "2020-11-01T18:30:00+00:00",
        1065,
        1079.95,
        1051.1,
        1072.3,
        7183119
      ],
      [
        "2020-11-02T18:30:00+00:00",
        1072,
        1079.4,
        1057.5,
        1062.55,
        7204782
      ],]
  }
}}
```

I want to convert candle data into `List<Historical>` 
Here is what I have tried

```
foreach (ArrayList item in historicalData["data"]["candles"])
                historicals.Add(new Historical(item));
```

But this gives me following error:

```
Cannot convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList
```

I have tried using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to diretly convert the string into the object using following code:

```
foreach (var item in historicalData["data"]["candles"]) {
                var historical = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Historical>(item.ToString());
```

But got this error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'QuantConnect.Brokerages.Zerodha.Messages.Historical' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Historical definition:

```
public struct Historical
    {
        public Historical(dynamic data)
        {
            TimeStamp = Convert.ToDateTime(data[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Open = Convert.ToDecimal(data[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            High = Convert.ToDecimal(data[2], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Low = Convert.ToDecimal(data[3], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Close = Convert.ToDecimal(data[4], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            Volume = Convert.ToUInt32(data[5], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            OI = data.Count > 6 ? Convert.ToUInt32(data[6], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) : 0;
        }

        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; }
        public decimal Open { get; }
        public decimal High { get; }
        public decimal Low { get; }
        public decimal Close { get; }
        public UInt32 Volume { get; }
        public UInt32 OI { get; }
    }
```

Is there a correct/elegant way to make it work. Also what I am missing something over here?

Comment: Have tried this but getting the error ``` Cannot deserialize the current JSON...```

Comment: Yup, i didn't notice that some web dev had decided to smash a bunch of typed data into a list and call it a candle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The main problem is this isn't valid json. However, let's fix it and assume it's correct. If this is what you are getting from some resources, I suggest you contact them and complain.
2. There are a bunch of ways to do this. Since you used JTokens, I will give you a similar answer.

**Given**

```
{
   "status":"success",
   "data":{
      "candles":[
         [
            "2020-11-01T18:30:00+00:00",
            1065,
            1079.95,
            1051.1,
            1072.3,
            7183119
         ],
         [
            "2020-11-02T18:30:00+00:00",
            1072,
            1079.4,
            1057.5,
            1062.55,
            7204782
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

And

```
public class Historical
{
   public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
   public decimal Open { get; set; }
   public decimal High { get; set; }
   public decimal Low { get; set; }
   public decimal Close { get; set; }
   public UInt32 Volume { get; set; }
   public UInt32 OI { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var jtoken = JToken.Parse(input);

var data = jtoken["data"]["candles"]
    .Select(x => new Historical
    {
       TimeStamp = x[0].Value<DateTime>(),
       Open = x[1].Value<decimal>(),
       Low = x[2].Value<decimal>(),
       High = x[3].Value<decimal>(),
       Close = x[4].Value<decimal>()
       //...
    });

foreach (var item in data)
   Console.WriteLine($"{item.TimeStamp},Open {item.Open},Low {item.Low} ...");
```

**Output**

```
2/11/2020 4:30:00 AM, Open 1065, Low 1079.95 ...
3/11/2020 4:30:00 AM, Open 1072, Low 1079.4 ...
```

<sub>***Note** : there are also many ways to deal with the datatime and how to configure Json.net or `TryParse` to give you the results you want. This is example is leaving this up to you and focusing solely on the projection.*</sub>

---

If you need this done in the constructor

```
public struct Historical
{
   public Historical(JToken x)
   {
      TimeStamp = x[0].Value<DateTime>();
      Open = x[1].Value<decimal>();
      Low = x[2].Value<decimal>();
      High = x[3].Value<decimal>();
      Close = x[4].Value<decimal>();
      ...
   }
   public DateTime TimeStamp { get; }
   public decimal Open { get; }
   public decimal High { get; }
   public decimal Low { get; }
   public decimal Close { get; }
   ...     
}

...

var data = jtoken["data"]["candles"].Select(x => new Historical(x));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But would there be way of doing this without updating the set property of the Historical class? The definition which I have only have get.